# Built a loop for a definite integral

Tags: matlab

I am trying to build a loop for a definite integral from `0` to `y` with step `0.1` for `y=0` to `y=20` and get a value for each loop iteration (varying `y`) in a diagram.

```
int(2.906663106*x*(1/(1+1.38*x^4))^.4311594203 - 3.458929096*x^5/((1/(1+1.38*x^4))^.5688405797*(1+1.38*x^4)^2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [integral](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function of Matlab and run this inside a for loop

```
val = zeros(1,201);

y_step  = 0.1;
y_max   = 20;

count   = 1;

for yy = 0:y_step:y_max

    fun = @(x) (2.906663106 .* x .* (1 ./ (1 + 1.38 .* x.^4)).^0.4311594203 - 3.458929096 .* x.^5 ./ ((1 ./ (1 + 1.38 .* x.^4)).^0.5688405797 .* (1 + 1.38 .* x.^4).^2));
    intgrl = integral(fun, 0, yy);

    val(count) = intgrl;
    count = count + 1;
end 

figure
plot(val)
```

You will have each value of the integral in the range `[0, yy]` during the loop saved in `val`.

**edit:** Edited answer due to more detailed question in comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response.as i mentioned the definite integral is between 0 and y (interval is [0,y]) with the y changing in each loop not x

Comment: iha ve tried to run the updated code and this error messages popped up Error using subsindex Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'function_handle'. Error in circ3 (line 11) intgrl = integral(fun, 0, yy);

Comment: Try to set all operators in the integral function to .* and ./ (I changed it as well in the answer).

Comment: Thanks alot my friend.I really appreciate it!